# Coordinate ring of an open set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve Exercise 3.1 (b) in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. I see a solution of it and it says that

> Any proper open set of $\mathbb A^1$ is $\mathbb A^1-S $, where $S$ is a finite number of points $\{p_1,\dots,p_n \}$. The coordinate ring of $\mathbb A^1-S$ is  $k[x,\frac {1} {x-p_1},\dots ,\frac {1} {x-p_n}]$.

How can i show that the coordinate ring of $\mathbb A^1-S$ is  $k[x,\frac {1} {x-p_1},\dots ,\frac {1} {x-p_n}]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look somewhere in Hartshorne, it is proven that the coordinate ring of the principal open set $D(f) \subseteq \text{Spec }A$ is $A_f$. Take $A=k[X]$ and $f=(X-p_1)\dots (X-p_n)$.